# Working with big nested object as state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

Hello fellow developers,

I'm junior developer and I'm working on a project with big nested object (example bellow) which ideally I want to use as react state that can be accessed from multiple places but I don't know which approach is best for this solution as I don't have many experiences yet. If you could give me some advice, code example or link to some tutorial or blog, it would be very helpful.

My current approach (example bellow) is to use **useContext without useReducer** because I just don't want to just export dispatch because I think is kinda ugly or not programmer friendly as you always have to define different type and payloads. Maybe I could wrap dispatch it in the functions but I'm just not sure about it. I was also thinking about using Redux, but I don't use that yet and according to what read that it can be overkill for this.

Thank you in advance.

```
{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    sections: [{
        id: string,
        pos_x: number,
        pos_y: number,
        rows: number,
        columns: number,
        curvature: number,
        skew: number,
        rotation: number,
        section_type: string,
        name: string,
        seats: [{
            id: string,
            row: number,
            column: number,
            is_disabled: boolean,
            category: string,
            name: string,
            created_at: string,
            updated_at: string,
            is_reserved: boolean,
            reserved_at: string,
            status: string,
            ticket: number
        }],
        total_seats: number,
        created_at: string,
        updated_at: string,
        available_seats: number,
        purchased_seats: number,
        reserved_seats: number
    }],
    creator: number,
    account: number,
    is_editable: boolean,
    total_seats: number,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string,
    event: number,
    available_seats: number,
    purchased_seats: number,
    reserved_seats: number
}
```

```
import React, {createContext, FC, useState} from 'react';
import {Seat, SeatMap, Section} from "../../types/seatmapData";

type UpdateSelectedSectionProps = (section: Section, seatIndex: number) => Section

export interface ISeatMap {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    sections: Section[],
    creator: number,
    account: number,
    isEditable: boolean,
    totalSeats: number,
    createdAt: string,
    updatedAt: string,
    event: number,
    availableSeats: number,
    purchasedSeats: number,
    reservedSeats: number
}

export interface ISeatMapContext extends ISeatMap {
    setName: (name: string) => void;
    setSections: (section: Section[]) => void;
    setId: (id: string) => void;
    setCreator: (creator: number) => void;
    setAccount: (account: number) => void;
    setIsEditable: (isEditable: boolean) => void;
    setTotalSeats: (totalSeats: number) => void;
    setCreatedAt: (createdAt: string) => void;
    setUpdatedAt: (updatedAt: string) => void;
    setEvent: (event: number) => void;
    setAvailableSeats: (availableSeats: number) => void;
    setPurchasedSeats: (purchasedSeats: number) => void;
    setReservedSeats: (reservedSears: number) => void;
    addSectionToSelected: (section: Section) => void;
    removeSectionsFromSelected: (section: Section) => void;
    clearSelectedSections: () => void;
    addSeatToSelected: (section: Section, seat: Seat) => void;
    removeSeatFromSelected: (section: Section, seat: Seat) => void;
    clearSelectedSeats: () => void;
    addSection: (section: Section) => void;
    removeSection: (section: Section) => void;
    removeSelectedSections: () => void;
    updateSection: (section: Section) => void;
    updateSelectedSeats: (updateFunction: UpdateSelectedSectionProps) => boolean;
    reserveSelectedSeats: (reserved: boolean, reservedAt: Date) => void;
    purchaseSelectedSeat: () => void;
    disableSelectedSeats: (disabled: boolean) => void;
    getSeatMap: () => void;
}

export const SeatMapContext = createContext<ISeatMapContext>(null!);

export interface SeatMapProviderProps extends FC {
    children: any;
    initialValue: SeatMap;
}

const SeatMapProvider = ({ children, initialValue }: SeatMapProviderProps) => {

    const [name, setName] = useState<string>(initialValue.name)
    const [sections, setSections] = useState<Section[]>(initialValue.sections)
    const [id, setId] = useState<string>(initialValue.id)
    const [creator, setCreator] = useState<number>(initialValue.creator)
    const [account, setAccount] = useState<number>(initialValue.account)
    const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState<boolean>(initialValue.is_editable)
    const [totalSeats, setTotalSeats] = useState<number>(initialValue.total_seats)
    const [createdAt, setCreatedAt] = useState<string>(initialValue.created_at)
    const [updatedAt, setUpdatedAt] = useState<string>(initialValue.updated_at)
    const [event, setEvent] = useState<number>(initialValue.event)
    const [availableSeats, setAvailableSeats] = useState<number>(initialValue.available_seats)
    const [purchasedSeats, setPurchasedSeats] = useState<number>(initialValue.purchased_seats)
    const [reservedSeats, setReservedSeats] = useState<number>(initialValue.reserved_seats)

    const [selectedSections, setSelectedSections] = useState<Section[]>([]);
    const [selectedSeats, setSelectedSeats] = useState<{section: Section, seat: Seat}[]>([]);

    const addSectionToSelected = (section: Section) => {
        setSelectedSections(prev => [...prev, section])
    }

    const removeSectionsFromSelected = (section: Section) => {
        setSelectedSections(prev => prev.filter(s => s.id === section.id))
    }

    const clearSelectedSections = () => {
        setSelectedSections([])
    }

    const addSeatToSelected = (section: Section, seat: Seat) => {
        setSelectedSeats(prev => [...prev, {section: section, seat: seat}])
    }

    const removeSeatFromSelected = (section: Section, seat: Seat) => {
        setSelectedSeats(prev => prev.filter(s => s.section.id === section.id && s.seat.id == seat.id))
    }

    const clearSelectedSeats = () => {
        setSelectedSeats([])
    }

    const addSection = (section: Section) => {
        setSections(prevState => [...prevState, section])
    }

    const removeSection = (section: Section) => {
        setSections(prevState => prevState.filter(s => s.id == section.id))
    }

    const removeSelectedSections = () => {
        if(selectedSections.length == 0) return

        setSections(prevState => {
            const notSelected: Section[] = []
            prevState.forEach(s => {
                let isSelected = false
                selectedSections.forEach(selected => {
                    if(selected.id == s.id) isSelected = true
                })
                if(!isSelected) notSelected.push(s)
            })
            return notSelected
        })
    }

    const updateSection = (section: Section) => {
        setSections((prevState) => {
            const index = prevState.findIndex(s => s.id === section.id)
            sections[index] = section
            return sections
        })
    }

    const updateSelectedSeats = (updateFunction: UpdateSelectedSectionProps): boolean => {
        if(selectedSections.length == 0 || selectedSeats.length == 0) return false
        const updateTime = new Date().toISOString()
        setSections(sections => {
            selectedSeats.forEach(({section, seat}) => {
                const sectionIndex = sections.findIndex(s => s.id === section.id)
                const seatIndex = sections[sectionIndex].seats.findIndex(s => s.id === seat.id)
                const newSection = updateFunction(sections[sectionIndex], seatIndex);
                sections[sectionIndex] = newSection
                sections[sectionIndex].updated_at = updateTime
            })
            return sections
        })
        setUpdatedAt(updateTime)
        return true
    }

    const reserveSelectedSeats = (reserved: boolean, reservedAt: Date) => {
        const updated = updateSelectedSeats((section, seatIndex) => {
            section.seats[seatIndex].is_reserved = reserved
            section.seats[seatIndex].reserved_at = reservedAt.toISOString()
            return section
        })
        if(updated) setReservedSeats(prev => reserved ? ++prev : --prev)
    }

    const purchaseSelectedSeat = () => {

    }

    const disableSelectedSeats = (disabled: boolean) => {
        const updated = updateSelectedSeats((section, seatIndex) => {
            section.seats[seatIndex].is_disabled = disabled
            if(disabled) section.total_seats--
            else section.total_seats++
            return section
        })
        if(updated) setTotalSeats(prev => disabled ? --prev : ++prev)
    }

    const getSeatMap = (): SeatMap => {
        return {
            name: name,
            sections: sections,
            id: id,
            creator: creator,
            account: account,
            is_editable: isEditable,
            total_seats: totalSeats,
            created_at: createdAt,
            updated_at: updatedAt,
            event: event,
            available_seats: availableSeats,
            purchased_seats: purchasedSeats,
            reserved_seats: reservedSeats,
        }
    }

    return (
        <SeatMapContext.Provider value={{
            name, setName,
            sections, setSections,
            id, setId,
            creator, setCreator,
            account, setAccount,
            isEditable, setIsEditable,
            totalSeats, setTotalSeats,
            createdAt, setCreatedAt,
            updatedAt, setUpdatedAt,
            event, setEvent,
            availableSeats, setAvailableSeats,
            purchasedSeats, setPurchasedSeats,
            reservedSeats, setReservedSeats,
            addSectionToSelected,
            addSeatToSelected,
            clearSelectedSeats,
            clearSelectedSections,
            purchaseSelectedSeat,
            removeSeatFromSelected,
            removeSectionsFromSelected,
            getSeatMap,
            addSection,
            removeSection,
            updateSection,
            removeSelectedSections,
            updateSelectedSeats,
            reserveSelectedSeats,
            disableSelectedSeats
        }}>
            {children}
        </SeatMapContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default SeatMapProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

State management libraries came to the table to reduce the pain when we are working with large and immutable states such as you are working with. You should use one of these solutions which is more suitable for your project. Yes, context is great but you have to be careful when you are updating state because it leads to rendering the whole tree (DOM) and might cause you some serious problems. I suggest sticking to the `redux` and using `reduxtoolkit` library or if your project it's already written in redux, you can use `immer` to have a better experience in using immutable state (you can use immer whenever you want, even with context).

if you want some other solutions, I suggest you read about observable states for example: `recoil` or `mobx`.

But if you still wanna use context, I suggest you read Kent C. Dodds useful article about context and his solution to create a store with context.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively